# Is using Assert.assertTrue(true); and assert Assert.fail(); good practise in JUnit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assertion

Is this good or bad practise of using Assert.assertTrue(true); and Assert.fail() in JUnit testing and why? 

I know there is also rule @Test (expected = Exception.class), but you can have more more than one exception which can be raised on tested method and if you don't want to have zillion testing methods for one tested method, this could be option. 

**The usecase is this:** You test method which can raise zero, one or more exception (in example to make it simple just one) and you want to test case that the call is ok so no exception should be raised and if you get into catch block you will raise Assert.fail(); then you want test case when exception should be raised, so you call in catch block Assert.assertTrue(true); to say "Yeah this is what I wanted". And from the test you can see in one test method when it should fail and when you run the test if its really behave like you want to. 
**Question is: Is this good or bad practise? Why?**

```
public void fooMethod(boolean paramenter) {
  if(false) {
    throw new Exception();
  }
}

@Test
public void testFooMethod() {

  try {
     myTestedClassMock.fooMethod(true); //should not raise exception
  } catch(Exception e) {
    Assert.fail();
  }  

  try {
    myTestedClassMock.fooMethod(false); //should raise exception
  } catch (Exception e) {
     Assert.assertTrue(true);
  }

}
```

Comment: This might be better off over at programmers.se, but I can't see the point of asserting true, you could just put a comment saying 'expected', that would probably be just as clear.

Comment: I personally would consider it bad practice, for your use case I would write two test methods and name then appropriately. If you have two exceptions then I would expect to have three test methods. That way you have to write more  test methods but you get much cleander test code and also the intent could be better communicated (via method name).

Comment: Learn to use the `ExpectedException` class.  It supersedes both the technique you've described, and the annotation-based technique given in one of the answers.

Comment: I know about ExpectedException and I mentioned it in my question. 
But if you have class with 20 methods or more and all will have 4 test cases it will be really messy. (I speak about application logic classes for controllers, this is the reason of so much methods, its no problem to have 40 methods in tested class ..)

Comment: No, you didn't mention the `ExpectedException` class in your question.  It will make this all much simpler if you learn to use it.  I'm not talking about the annotation - the annotation is now obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always leave out `Assert.assertTrue(true)` because `assertTrue` is designed for a different purpose. It is there to check general conditions involving multiple boolean items, e.g.

```
Assert.assertTrue(t == null ||| minSize < 0 || t.size() > minSize);
```

Asserting a constant `true` always succeeds without a trace, so you can completely remove this line from your code. Catching situations when an expected exception is *not* thrown is done by placing `Assert.fail();` immediately after the line of test code that must throw an exception, with a message indicating that an expected exception has not been thrown.

> if you don't want to have zillion testing methods for one tested method, this could be option.

Typically, "zillion testing methods" is a better option. As an alternative, you could catch `Exception` or `RuntimeException` in your test, rather than catching each individual exception. This is a questionable practice in production code, but it is absolutely fine in the testing code when you must ensure that no exception is thrown.

However, having an `Assert.fail();` is not an uncommon shortcut, and it is usually acceptable, too. It is a good idea to add a message describing the reason behind the failure, so that the people who maintain your code do not have to read through your tests to see what is going on. When you catch an exception, its message is a good candidate for the failure message of the test.

Comment: And is it also better option if you are have MVC application and you are doing test for application logic clasess which have methods that are called from controllers. And this tested clasess can have 3-4 methods but also 20 - 40, it depends on case. So if you have more than one test method for each tested method it could be really messy. Thanks

Comment: I would say: having 20 to 40 methods on a single class already has a certain "bad smell" on it.

Comment: I wouldn't call `Assert.fail()` with no argument acceptable, personally.  Especially when there's an informative exception available to use as a message.

Comment: @VGR Thank you very much for the comment! This makes perfect sense, I edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

It is a good practice to use `fail()` however not like you do it. That's because you want to let the test fail if an exception occurs. This you can do without catching this exception. If one appears then the test fails.

In the second case instead of using `assertTrue(true)` add `fail()` after your method-invocation:

```
myTestedClassMock.fooMethod(true); //should not raise exception

try {
    myTestedClassMock.fooMethod(false); //should raise exception
    Assert.fail("Exception expected!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // exception handling
}
```

This makes your intentions more clear and you see that the test fails if no exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks but in first case you have to have the method also in try - catch block otherwise will your compiler cry like a baby - look at the definition of the fooMethod it has throw in its body so you have to somehow handle in test by try catch or throw after method name

Comment: Not necessarily: you can add the `throws` declaration to the definition of the test method. It won't change anything of the usefulness of the test. This would be my option to do.

Comment: yeah then it will be ok =)

Comment: No need to assert true in the catch block to indicate the test case success. is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Is there something missing is second case?
I would rather do the next checking:

```
  try {
    myTestedClassMock.fooMethod(false);
    Assert.fail("should raise exception");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    //Check if this is the exception you expected
  }
```

What about the first case, if exception will be thrown, it will fail the test anyway, so there is no need for `Assert.fail()` and `try-catch` block

Answer (score 1):

Some good practices regarding your source code.

First: there is only ONE assert within each and any test method. So, when that method fails, you know immediately where to look to.

That also helps with your problem:

```
@Test
public void testFooMethodThatShouldNotThrow() throws WhatEverException {
   bar.foo(true)
```

So, if foo() throws in the above code, the unit test fails. It doesn't matter that we added a throws clause.

When you expect an exception to be thrown; then say so:

```
@Test(expected=WhateverException.class)
public void testFooMethodThatShouldThrow() {
  bar.foo(false);
}
```

If you want to check certain properties of the thrown exception; then you would do a

```
@Test
public void bla {
  try {
    bar.foo();
    fail("should have thrown");
  catch (WhateverException e) {
    assertThat(e.getMessage(), is("bla blub flubber"));
  }
```

for example.

Finally: there is exactly one assertThat that one ever needs: **assertThat**. Forget about all the others; and learn to use that one.